# How To Insert and update three MySQL table using Hibernate Java?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to Java server side programming using Hibernate, how to insert and update the Three tables at a time using hibernate. I am developing an app i.e. online food ordering system.

**Order Header Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_headers` (
  `merchant_code` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bill_number` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payment_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_status` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_date` date NOT NULL,
  `order_time` time NOT NULL,
  `sub_total` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `VAT` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `grand_total` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bill_number`)
)
```

**Order Details Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `order_details` (
  `merchant_code` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bill_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_number` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`order_number`)
)
```

**Item Details Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `items_ordered` (
  `items_ordered_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `merchant_code` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_number` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_code` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_short_desc` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `custom_instructions` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `quantity` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `value` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
   PRIMARY KEY (`items_ordered_id`)
)
```

**Scenarios**

1. (Insert) At first When user ordered **3 items**. Create one row in **order_headers** table with **bill_number 1**(bill_number is auto increment), then create one row in **order_details** table with **order_number 1**(order_number is auto increment) then insert all the **3 items** in **items_ordered** with **order_number 1**table.
2. (Update and Insert) Now same user ordered **2 items** with same **bill_number**, Now **update** going on in **order_headers** table to update `subtotal`,`VAT`,`grand_total` have **bill_number 1**, then insert process in **order_details** table with **order_number 2**(order_number is auto increment) bill number is same as **1**,then insert all the **2 items** in **items_ordered** table with **order_number 2**.

I know about `one to one`, `many to one` and `one to many` (With two tables no problem, when comes to three tables like this scenarios can't get how to use).

please Anyone suggest me, Which Hibernate mapping process will be best for this process and How to use it.

Comment: Shouldn't the details table just keep track of the header id instead of repeating all those fields in both tables?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils In my concept is like customer online order at Restaurant and Hotels.Now user going to place new order then one `bill_number` and `order_number` will generate now show the `order_number` to customer.Now the user order second set of dishes means generate new `order_number` not to generate new `bill_number`. After user completed the orders. Show bill_number + order_numbers`(For Ex: Your Bill_number is 1, your order number is 1,2,3)` finally fetch all orders show to users.

Comment: check out CascadeType and how you can use Cascading to insert data into multiple tables. It might help you.

Comment: Please, add sketch  persistences with `@OneToMany` to better understand  your table's associations.